# Is it possible to use direct object pronouns with the verbs "aimer" and "connaître" when they refer to things?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, complément-cod

According to grammar books, direct object pronouns are used with  the verbs "aimer" and "connaître"  only when they refer to people. And when they refer to things they combine with the pronoun "ça" or nothing, like in

*Est-ce que tu aimes le riz? - Oui,j'aime ça.*

or

*Est-ce que tu connais le riz? - Oui, je connais*.

But I heard some people say in similar situations

*Je l'aime.*

or

*Je le connais*.

Is the usage of direct object pronouns  with  the  "aimer" and "connaître" which refer to things acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable. No reason why not, meaning, those pronouns are not restricted to representing persons. In fact, you _have to_ use those, because there are no separate pronouns for objects.

Answer (score 12):

It is grammatically correct to use *le, la, les* ... for objects. Those pronouns are not restricted to persons, there are no separate pronouns for objects. For example:

> Tu connais ce livre?
>
> Oui, je **le** connais.

is entirely correct, idiomatic, etc etc., and there isn't really any other way to say that. In particular, you couldn't say *Oui, j'aime ça*, using *ça* to mean *le livre*.

Now, one thing to note, is that in the example above, *le* refers to ***ce** livre*, which is a specific *livre* in the conversation. If there is no specific object that the pronoun in the answer would refer to, it's a bit more questionable, in terms of **usage**. Here are possible answers with approximate indications about usage frequency (subjective):

> Tu aimes **le riz**? (*rice* in general)
>
> Oui, j'aime **ça** (*ça = rice* in general, quite common)
>
> Oui, j'aime! (no pronoun, quick and simple, common in conversation)
>
> Oui, je **l**'aime (possible, not common, sounds "funny")

The issue is not that rice is an object, but rather that *le riz* is not specific. If it is a specific eg brand of rice, the situation is a bit different, and here are possible answers, with again an approximate indication of their usage frequency (subjective again):

> Tu aimes **ce** riz? (*ce = some specific rice*)
>
> Oui, je **l**'aime (*l' = ce riz*, specific, common)
>
> Oui, j'aime! (no pronoun, quick and simple, common in conversation)
>
> Oui, j'aime **ça** (possible, maybe less common)

Comment: It is not "acceptable" (not very good but good enough), it is standard procedure.

Comment: Cela me laisse coïte que l'on donne un vote négatif à une réponse comme celle-ci.

Comment: @LPH: "acceptable" has a specific meaning in linguistics, which basically amounts to "native speakers won't think it's peculiar".

Comment: @psmears "The terms'grammatical'and 'ungrammatical'are commonly used by nonspecialists as synonyms of'acceptable'and 'unacceptable'" (CoGEL). "fully acceptable" would have been better; anyway, what was meant was not the pseudo-linguistic/contested term "acceptable".

Comment: @LPH: How do you know that? There's not a lot to go on, granted, but that was how I read it at least!

Comment: @psmears   How do I know? From the interaction I had the displeasure to be involved in witjh this user.  // In any case, this is not a matter of native speaker's feelings about a given usage, but a much more basic question of rock-bottom grammaticality; in such matters the speaker's feelings are soon dismissed as criterions of correctness.

Comment: @LPH Didn't see that interaction so will have to take your word for it. But tbh I'm not sure which rocks' bottoms you're using as "criterions" of correctness that have more validity than what native speakers find acceptable :) But each to their own!

Comment: @psmears rock bottom wrong: "le table, il disont, pomme la mangé, etc".

Comment: @LPH: OK. I've not come across native speakers that would be OK with that, but again I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Read ' "Rock-bottom" '. // Il n'y a que vous qui puissiez voir un débat "CoGEL vs CGEL", vous inventez, encore une fois.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Je ne pense pas avoir pris de position contre la grammaire générative ; il faudrait d'abord que je connaisse ce sujet, ce qui n'est pas le cas. Si on peut déterminer dans mes opinions une telle tendance, elle est indépendante de tout stimulus issu de la linguistique de Chomski.

Comment: @LPH _Mere, basic, minimal_ etc. ton emploi de _rock-bottom_ comme modificateur est vraiment pas idiomatique à mon avis. Avec _wrong_ on se demande même si c'est une erreur moindre, plutôt que grave voire absolue, si ce n'était des exemples. Ok, le bénéfice du doute.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t SOED, **rock-bottom**: fundamental, firmly grounded.